# Null pointer exception in TestNG

Tags: selenium, testng

My code is:

```
package ant;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class NewTestNG {
    public WebDriver driver; 

    @BeforeMethod
    public void LAunchbrowser() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void main() {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement a=   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']"));
        action.moveToElement(a).click().sendKeys("Shirt").build().perform();    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@value='Search']")).click();
    }
}
```

I'm getting NullPointerException:

```
FAILED: main

    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:44)
    at ant.NewTestNG.main(NewTestNG.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Still not working.

FAILED: main
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: .//*[@id='gs_htif0']
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:09'

Comment: That's another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `LaunchBrowser()` you declared `driver` again instead of using the class instance. Change it to

```
@BeforeMethod
public void LaunchBrowser() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

and it should work. The problem is that when you declared `driver` in `LaunchBrowser()`, the scope of that variable is inside the method only so the class variable, `driver` doesn't get used. So when you are outside of the method and try to reference `driver`, it's `null`... thus the exception.

You really need to spend some time learning how to debug your own programs. If you put a break point at the start of the script and stepped through it, you should have been able to find this yourself.

Comment: If you found this (or any) answer helpful, please upvote it. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: No my code is not executed successfully.Its giving me an error which I posted in previous comment

Comment: Yes but the null pointer exception is fixed which is the topic of this question. To fix the new problem, you'll need to ask a new question.